# Showing content sent from server to client at localhost in a browser

Tags: python, localhost, file-transfer

Im writing a simple client server program in python and i wanted to show elements in a browser i "received" from the "server". For that purpose i wrote "80" as PORT number but i cant see any activity although the program works fine and "puts" or "gets" elements. So my question is how to show the response message and the content sent from server when i search for "127.0.0.1" in a browser. I hope i could express myself correctly. Thanks for any help.

EDIT :Im still trying to find a way, I really couldnt find an answer, i really would be very thankful for help, Im also writing out the data sent from server at clients side but nothing changes the answer is "EMPTY RESPONSE"..

Heres my code:

```
import socket
import os
import sys
HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 80
socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
socket.listen(1)
while (1):
    conn, addr = socket.accept()
    choice= conn.recv(1024).decode()
    if (choice== '3'):
        file=conn.recv(1024).decode()
        with open(file, 'wb') as write_file:
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                if not data:
                    break
                write_file.write(data)
                break
        print('received')
    elif (choice== '1'):
        filee=conn.recv(1024).decode()
        with open(filee, 'rb') as send_file:
            for data in send_file:
                conn.sendall(data.encode())
        print("sent")
conn.close()
socket.close()
```

CLIENT.py

```
import socket, os.path, datetime, sys
HOST = '127.0.0.1'    
PORT = 80
def put(choice):
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
    socket1.send(choice.encode())
    file=input("file?")
    socket1.send(file.encode())
    with open(file, 'rb') as send_file:
        for data in send_file:
            socket1.sendall(data.encode())
    print('sent')
    socket1.close()
    return
def get(choice):
    socket1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket1.connect((HOST, PORT))
    socket1.send(choice.encode())
    file=input("file?")
    socket1.send(file.encode())
    with open(file, 'wb') as write_file:
        while True:
            data = socket1.recv(1024).decode()
            if not data:
                break
            write_file.write(data)
    write_file.close()
    print('received')
    socket1.close()
    return
while(True):
    print("1.   read\n")
    print("3.   send\n")

    choice= (input("choice?"))
    if (choice== '3'):
        put(choice)
        break
    elif (choice== '1'):
        get(choice)
        break
```

Comment: If you want the browser to be the client instead of the python script, then you will probably need to return HTML to display whatever you want in the browser. You might also want to look into using [`websockets`](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) instead of the `sockets` library or use a web framework like Flask or Django.

Comment: thank you for your advice but this isnt actually what im trying to make. Isnt it possible to see´, what is sent by server to that client in python script?

Comment: Yes if you print out what is received by your python client you can see what was sent. Or if you use a program like Wireshark to monitor packets.

Comment: Ive tried this too but i get "ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE" error although i sent things to client.. its really sad i cant find anything about this in any topic